# Flutter: When I play video in landscape the App Bar shows how to avoid that using Flutter_Youtube_player

Tags: flutter, dart

Her is the code that I'm using kindly help me out.

return  Scaffold(

```
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(widget.videoItem.video.title),

    ),

    body: Container(

      child: YoutubePlayer(
        controller: _controller,
        showVideoProgressIndicator: true,

        onReady: () {
          print('Player is ready');
          _isPlayerReady = true;
        },),),);
```

Comment: your question is not clear! What do you mean by the app shows?

Comment: I'm Sorry, I'm missed typed. (App bar)* as you can see in the the Image.